# Is there a way to make spring ignore the "not compatible spring cloud version" problem

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

I have reached a bit of a deadend. Because of the End of Support for Spring Boot 2.7 i am upgrading to Spring Boot 3.1. My application is using Spring Cloud AWS for the SQS feature.
The Problem is that the Spring Cloud AWS package is only compatible with Spring Boot 3.0.X
When i try to run the application i am getting the following error:

> Description:
>
> Your project setup is incompatible with our requirements due to
> following reasons:
>
> - Spring Boot [3.1.2] is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train
>
> Action:
>
> Consider applying the following actions:
>
> - Change Spring Boot version to one of the following versions [3.0.x] . You can find the latest Spring Boot versions here
>   [https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#learn].  If you want to learn
>   more about the Spring Cloud Release train compatibility, you can visit
>   this page [https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud#overview] and check
>   the [Release Trains] section. If you want to disable this check, just
>   set the property [spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false]

Because of some Requirements it is not possible to only upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.
Is there an Option to make Spring cloud ignore the version mismatch?
Or do i have to wait until the Spring Cloud AWS package gets updated to Spring Boot 3.1

Comment: The solution is in the error. `spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false` however I then highly doubt your application will still start due to compatibility issues and will fail with missing classes, method signatures that have changed etc.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It seems to work after disabling the error. I must have been blind while reading the error message to miss this part.

Comment: The problem is that "it seems to work". There is no garantuee that it actually will work flawlessy. So when issues arise you are on your own.

Comment: Yes i know, that it is no optimal but i think it is the only solution i have.